# Shiny - postgres database query using dplyr and a reactive value

Tags: postgresql, shiny, dplyr

I'm using a postgres db for a shiny app, and I'm having trouble getting a dplyr query to work.

I have the following reactive. si.division is a dataframe, and input$si_division is a select input:

```
si_division_selected <- reactive({
  si.division %>% 
    filter(division_name %in% input$si_division) %>% 
    select(division_code) %>% 
    unlist(use.names = FALSE)
})
```

I'm trying to pass this into a dplyr query using src_pool

```
industry_division_code <- src_pool(pool) %>% tbl("si_alldata") %>%
      translate_sql(division_code %in% si_division_selected()) %>% 
      select(industry_code)
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an
>   object of class "c('sql', 'character')

I have also tried:

```
 industry_division_code <- src_pool(pool) %>% tbl("si_alldata") %>%
      filter(division_code %in% si_division_selected()) %>%
      select(industry_code)
```

Which returns:

> Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) :    RS-DBI
>   driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  syntax error at or
>   near "SI_DIVISION_SELECTED" LINE 5: WHERE ("division_code" IN
>   SI_DIVISION_SELECTED()))

If I load the file into R instead of using the database I have no issues:

```
industry_division_code <- si_alldata %>%
    filter(division_code %in% si_division_selected()) %>%
    select(industry_code)
```

Comment: why do you use `translate_sql` (and why with two sets of parenthesis) instead of `filter`?

Comment: I updated my question to include the attempt using filter().  Also removed extra parenthesis, same result.

Comment: How does your query look like when you do `%>% explain` on it? Also, how many elements are in `si_division_selected`? `%in%` won't work with less than 2 elements.

Comment: only one element, but using == instead of %in% returned same result.  explain() returns:

`<SQL>
SELECT "industry_code" AS "industry_code"
FROM (SELECT *
FROM "si_alldata"
WHERE ("division_code" = SI_DIVISION_SELECTED()))`

Comment: Assigning the reactive and passing it to the query seems to work:

Assign:
`si_division_selected <- si_division_selected()`

Then pass:

  `industry_division_code <- collect(src_pool(pool) %>% tbl("si_alldata") %>%
    filter(division_code == si_division_selected) %>%
    select(industry_code))`

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to keep using `si_division_selected()` as the value that is passed in the filter, then you should be able to use the `rlang` package to force the evaluation of the function, so the line would look like this: `filter(division_code %in%  !! si_division_selected())`.  Although, your current solution of just saving the results off to a variable would be my preferred avenue.